# Filtering data by four columns

Tags: select, oracle10g, filtering

I have some data in ORACLE in following format-
[image]

Now I want to filter this data as follows-
I want to exclude those rows where all col1, col2, col3, col4 are 'N'

[image]

I tried following so that I can get columns where all col1, col2, col3, col4 are not 'N'

```
Select * from Table1
Where (col1 != ‘N’ and col2 != ‘N’ and col3 != ‘N’ and col4 != ‘N’)
```

But it is not working.
What extra condition do I need to include here to get the desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like

```
Select * from Table1
Where not (col1 = ‘N’ and col2 = ‘N’ and col3 = ‘N’ and col4 = ‘N’)
```

or

```
Select * from Table1
Where  (col1 != ‘N’ or col2 != ‘N’ or col3 != ‘N’ or col4 != ‘N’)
```